# How to access docker.sock on a container instance inside an azure container group?

Tags: azure, docker, containers, traefik, azure-container-instances

I am doing a small system which deploys azure container groups via Rest. On the container groups I have multiple instances that are load balanced via Traefik. For example I have a container group with two containers plus a traefik container that redirects requests to the other two containers.

The problem with this solution is being able to access docker.sock on the traefik container. Without docker.sock Traefik is blind, and cannot detect the existing containers.

I have tried a couple of approaches, but with no success.

Is it possible to access docker.sock on an azure container instance?

Thanks for your support.

Answer (score 1):

We don't enable access to docker.sock from ACI because the service is built to provide a managed container solution, so access to the underlying host and docker running isn't available.

Depending on your scenario, we'll be bringing in LB support for Azure VNETs later this year that should be able to help. Hopefully you can find alternative routes but feel free to share details and I'm happy to help if possible.

Comment: Container-managed TLS with managed certificates would obviate the need for docker-socket access. With the sidecar approach you need the certificate enrolling sidecar to restart the TLS proxy sidecar.